# Solve a transcendental equation

Tags: numerical-methods, transcendental-equations

I have the following complicated equation $e^{a t} = 2 \cos(bt)$, needs to be solved for t. Any possibility of getting analytic solution? If not, can we solve it in Mathematica?

Comment: One thing to note for sure is that $e^{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ get arbitrarily close to each other for negative off multiples of $\pi / 2$. You might have to do this numerically unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You won't find a full analytic solution.  If $t$ is small you can use the first terms of the Taylor series to get an approximation, solving $1+at=1-\frac {(bt)^2}2$.  You can solve it numerically with any root finder.  You should have an infinite set of solutions where $t$ has the opposite sign from $a$.  Once $t$ gets a little large $e^{at}$ will be small and the solutions will be close to odd multiples of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, only numerical methods could solve this transcendental equation.

As Ross Millikan answered, the case where the solution $t$ would be small is quite interesting. But, instead of using Taylor expansion for an approximate solution, we can also consider [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) using degree $1$ for numerator and degree $n$ for denominator. The first solutions would then be 
$$t_{(1)}=\frac{2 a}{3 a^2+2 b^2}$$
$$t_{(2)}=\frac{3 \left(3 a^2+2 b^2\right)}{a \left(13 a^2+12 b^2\right)}$$
$$t_{(3)}=\frac{4 a \left(13 a^2+12 b^2\right)}{75 a^4+96 a^2 b^2+22 b^4}$$
$$t_{(4)}=\frac{5 \left(75 a^4+96 a^2 b^2+22 b^4\right)}{a \left(541 a^4+880 a^2 b^2+340
   b^4\right)}$$
$$t_{(5)}=\frac{6 a \left(541 a^4+880 a^2 b^2+340 b^4\right)}{4683 a^6+9240 a^4 b^2+5160 a^2 b^4+602 b^6}$$

For illustration purposes, considering only the positive solution for $a=4$ and $b=3$, we should get, as approximations,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & t_{(n)} & t_{(n)} \approx \\
 1 & \frac{4}{33} & 0.121212 \\
 2 & \frac{99}{632} & 0.156646 \\
 3 & \frac{2528}{17403} & 0.145262 \\
 4 & \frac{87015}{585512} & 0.148614 \\
 5 & \frac{1171024}{7932791} & 0.147618
\end{array}
\right)$$ while the "exact" solution would be $0.147845$.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint:

$$ 1 = 2 (e^{iz} - e^{-i\bar z}) = 2 (e^{i(b+ia)} - e^{-i(b-ia)}) $$